# How to call a bunch of subdirectories Makefile from a top level Makefile with different targets

Tags: makefile

I have a top level Makefile that define a list of subdirectories containing sub-Makefiles.

Each sub-Makefile define the same targets: all, install, clean, test, verify, style...

How do I make the top level Makefile call all my subdirectories Makefile with the same target ?

It works for the default target, like this:

```
SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3

all: subdirs

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)
```

But how do I extend that to the other non default targets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU make you could use the [`MAKECMDGOALS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKECMDGOALS) and the [`filter` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-filter):

```
SUBDIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3
TARGETS := all install clean test verify style

$(TARGETS): subdirs
    @echo making top $@

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(filter $(TARGETS),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: subdirs $(TARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)

%::
    @echo making top $@
```

Demo:

```
$ make --no-print-directory all install foobar
make -C dir1 all install
make -C dir2 all install
make -C dir3 all install
making top all
making top install
making top foobar
```

Note that `filter` is needed to avoid passing top-only goals to the sub-makes.

If, for any reason, this `MAKECMDGOALS` based solution does not work for you, here are some other, but a bit more complex, solutions.

#### Target-specific variables

Target-specific variables propagate to prerequisites. So you can define a pattern-specific variable (`SUBGOAL`) for each of your top-level goals and use it in the subdir's recipe:

```
SUBDIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3

all: SUBGOAL := all
all: subdirs
    @echo making top $@

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(SUBGOAL)

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)
```

If you have many such top-level goals and use GNU make you can factorize a bit with the [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) and [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) GNU make functions:

```
SUBDIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3
TARGETS := all install clean test verify style

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(t): GOAL := $(t)))

$(TARGETS): subdirs
    @echo making top $@

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(GOAL)

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS) $(TARGETS)
```

One important drawback is that as you use the same phony subdirectory target (`dir1`) for several top phony targets (`all`, `install`...) you cannot invoke make with several top goals:

```
$ make --no-print-directory all install
make -C dir1 all
make -C dir2 all
make -C dir3 all
making top all
making top install
```

will only make `all` in the subdirectories. If this is a problem you can use the next solution.

#### One phony target (`all-dir1`) per top-subdirectory combination

Let's do this programmatically with a 2-variables macro and a [`foreach-eval-call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) combination (GNU make only):

```
SUBDIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3
TARGETS := all install clean test verify style

$(TARGETS): subdirs
    @echo making top $@

TARGETS_X_SUBDIRS :=

# $(1): top target
# $(2): subdirectory target
define TARGETS_X_SUBDIRS_RULES
$(1): $(1)-$(2)

$(1)-$(2):
    $(MAKE) -C $(2) $(1)

TARGETS_X_SUBDIRS += $(1)-$(2)
endef
$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(foreach s,$(SUBDIRS),$(eval $(call TARGETS_X_SUBDIRS_RULES,$(t),$(s)))))

.PHONY: $(TARGETS) $(TARGETS_X_SUBDIRS)
```

Demo:

```
$ make --no-print-directory all install
make -C dir1 all
make -C dir2 all
make -C dir3 all
making top all
make -C dir1 install
make -C dir2 install
make -C dir3 install
making top install
```

Comment: Thats a very complete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Renaud's answer is more complete, but I also found this technique that worked fine for my use case:

```
all:

%:
    make -C dir1 $@
    make -C dir2 $@
    make -C dir3 $@
```

In this case, I don't have the subdirs list in a variable, but they are spelled out in the commands for the generic target `%:`. It requires to add an extra `make -C` in front of every subdirectory, and a `@` in the back, but otherwise pretty maintainable and easy to read.

But it probably would not work if there was any other targets specific to the top-level Makefile.

Comment: I don't see how this answers your original question, which was "But how do I extend that to the other non default targets ?" This will still invoke the first target in each subdirectory's Makefile, no?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here looking far a generic wrapper Makefile that forwards any targets given to it to a set of (directories containing) Makefiles and works well in parallel, I recently had occasion to device such a wrapper. It has the advantage of not requiring any knowledge of targets supported by the Makefiles being called, and crucially for me will build the forwarded targets in parallel when the `-j` flag is provided.

I'm adding this answer because the other answers either makes assumptions about the valid targets that can be forwarded, or executes the wrapped Makefiles serially rather than in parallel.

```
# Define the directories and Makefiles to forward the targets to
# here for illustrative purposes. Could just as well be passed in
# on the command-line, wildcarded, or found (shell find).
MAKE_DIRS := some/path/containing/a/Makefile some/other/path/containing/some/other/Makefile
MAKE_FILES := some/path/to/a/Makefile some/other/path/to/another/Makefile

# Define all the passed-in targets as depending on
# the directories and Makefiles
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKE_DIRS) $(MAKE_FILES)

# Generate one recipe for each directory that makes a recursive call
# to the directory with the requested targets. The '+' will make sure
# it is executed, even when -n, -q or -t is given
$(foreach MAKE_DIR,$(MAKE_DIRS),$(eval $(MAKE_DIR): ; +$(MAKE) -C $(MAKE_DIR) $(MAKECMDGOALS)))

# Do the same for each Makefile with -f instead of -C.
$(foreach MAKE_FILE,$(MAKE_FILES),$(eval $(MAKE_FILE): ; +$(MAKE) -f $(MAKE_FILE) $(MAKECMDGOALS))) 

# Define everything in this file as phony so it always executes.
.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS) $(MAKE_DIRS) $(MAKE_FILES)
```

This really helped me with a project containing five compile-variations on a large CMake project. The CMake project contained thousands of small pieces and one gigantic blob which, by itself, took around 4 minutes to compile. After a code update, and running a variant of the above Makefile with `-j5` the small things would complete quickly, and I could sit back and relax for four minutes while the five large blobs compiled in parallel. Getting turn-around time down from 20+ to 4+ minutes was definitely worth the effort of setting it up.